# Localization did not worker after deploying the project

Tags: c#, deployment, localization

I developed Windows Application that uses Localization, before deploying the project every thing works good -Localization- , but after deploying the project and setup it on my machine the Localization did not worked

This is the code used for Localization

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");

// The local language (Arabic Egypt)

Comment: `the Localization did not worked` Thanks for explaining your problem so clearly.

Comment: I think it is clear... this is the problem all : the localization did not worked outside visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to copy the folder that contains **resources.dll** to Application start up path

**for example** : the folder 'ar-EG' that contains OpticalSystem.resources.dll as a dll resources

This folder located on 'Your_ApplicationPath\bin\Debug\'

**Note that :** the machine must have the local language you use in languages list